# Hot to put html table cells exactly under each other?

Tags: html, html-table

I have following html code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<table border="1" style="width:300px">
  <tr>
    <td>Avaldus</td>
    <td>Staatus</td>
    <td>Kehtivusaeg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sõidutoetus<td>
    <td>Arvestatud<td>
    <td>kuni 1. jaanuarini</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I look it in my browser it looks very bad, I want columns to be exactly under each other, so Sõidutoetus would be under Avaldus and Arvestatud under Staatus etc. But they are not. How could I make it right?

Comment: Now I noticed that I have missing slashes in <td>Sõidutoetus<td and <td>Arvestatud<td>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use end tags to end your table cells.

The first two cells in the send row have start tags after them instead of end tags.

```
<td>Sõidutoetus<td> <!-- needs a / -->
<td>Arvestatud<td>  <!-- ditto -->
```

Alternatively, just omit them. End tags for table cells are optional in HTML.

```
<td>Sõidutoetus
<td>Arvestatud
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong. You have not properly close the table columns. Use the below code.

```
 <table border="1" style="width:300px">
  <tr>
    <td>Avaldus</td>
    <td>Staatus</td>
    <td>Kehtivusaeg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Sõidutoetus</td>
      <td>Arvestatud</td>
    <td>kunijaanuarini</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should provide a more informative explanation than "your code is wrong" so your answer doesn't read like a game of spot-the-difference.